# packages directories not copied over

Tags: tidesdk

I'm developing an app with Ext JS 4 and TideSDK. Ext JS uses a couple directories with name of "packages" but when I package the app using the TideSDK Developer it doesn't copy an packages directories to the .app recursively. This breaks Ext JS during development so is there a way to allow the packages directories to be copied over to the .app?

This looks to be an issue with TideSDK Developer and not TideSDK itself. Confirmation?

[EDIT]

I created a new project, added some directories for a test:

/Resources/packages
/Resources/foo/packages

Build the app with TideSDK Developer and checked the contents of the .app and there is no /Resources/packages and no /Resources/foo/packages. There was the /Resources/foo directory but no packages. Ran the bundle with tidebuilder.py and the packages directories are there as wanted. So this is a bug with TideSDK Developer but is there a way to work around it? (will file a bug in github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is just how TideSDK Developer is created, this is how it launches the app (notice the 5th line for ignore):

```
PackageProject.currentAppPID = TiDev.launchPython(
                [PackageProject.desktopPackage.toString(),
                "-d", dest.toString(), // Staging directory
                "-a", assets.toString(), // Assets path
                "-i", 'dist,packages', // Ignore
                "-n", // Don't include the installer
                "-r", // Run it!
                "-v", // Verbose
                "-s", basePath.toString(), // SDK path
                appdir.toString()]);
```